# Firefox in Ubuntu : how to automate basic authentication password confirm dialog

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, authentication

I have an Ubuntu workstation with Firefox always open on a (autorefreshing) web page protected by basic auth.

At startup, I have autologin and automatic Firefox start on the page and I have saved the basic auth credentials.

I'd like to confirm in some automated way the username/password dialog box which pops up on the first opening of the page, or I'd like to know if there's any hack to avoid this dialog box.

I tried setting the homepage to http://username%3Apassword@myserver/mypage put that doesn't stop confirmation dialog boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) or [IronAHK](http://code.google.com/p/ironahk/). I haven't used either of them, but they're basically tools for simulating mouse and keyboard events, which sounds like one way of solving your problem.

Edit: See the comments for the exact answer.

Comment: Yay! it works with 
WID=`xdotool search "Authentication Required" | head -1`
xdotool windowfocus $WID
xdotool key Return

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For people coming from google:

The easiest way to prevent that annoying popup is to got to "about":config" and add a new integer entry:
Name: network.http.phishy-userpass-length
Value: 255

With this in place you can then use `http://username:password@myserver/mypage` and there will be no confirmation boxes.
More information can be found at http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.phishy-userpass-length

Answer (score 1):

There is an automation addon for firefox called [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863).
I have not used it first hand and cannot vouch it it will help you solve your problem.
You could give it a short try.

Comment: I am afraid the unattended parts are not available on linux:
http://wiki.imacros.net/Web_Scripting#How_to_run_iMacros_unattended

Answer (score 0):

[PasswordProfiler](http://nic-nac-project.de/~kaosmos/profilepass-FF-RDF-0.3.10.xpi) is protection like this is very weak and a smart user can bypass it easily.

Comment: I do not need to secure this workstation, it's in a safe and locked place available only to authorized people, the problem is automating the password submission.

Comment: FYI to those with edit authority, link is dead

Answer (score 0):

xdotool is really useful! Thanks!

This is my script in Ubuntu Karmic. I have a key combination that launches this code, so I can get really fast to a htaccess password protected site:

```
#!/bin/bash

#If Firefox is not running, wait 4 seconds to open.       
if [ "$(pidof firefox)" ]
  then
    timetosleep=1
  else
    timetosleep=4
fi

#Launch firefox
firefox http://wiki.example.org &

#Sleep until the window comes up
sleep $timetosleep

#Press enter!
WID=`xdotool search --title Identi`
xdotool windowactivate $WID
xdotool key Return
```

PD: As my firefox is in spanish I search for "Identificación" instead of "Authentication".