# firefox in ubuntu : how to automate basic authentication password confirm dialog

Tags: firefox, authentication, ubuntu, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox in Ubuntu : how to automate basic authentication password confirm dialog](https://superuser.com/questions/46191/firefox-in-ubuntu-how-to-automate-basic-authentication-password-confirm-dialog)

I have an ubuntu workstation with  firefox always open on a (autorefreshing) web page protected by basic auth.

At startup, I have autologin and automatic firefox start on the page and I have saved the basic auth credentials.

I'd like to confirm in some automated way the username/password dialog box which pops up on the first opening of the page, or I'd like to know if there's any hack to avoid this dialog box.

I tried setting the homepage to  http://username:password@myserver/mypage  put that doesn't stop confirmation dialog boxes.

Thanks
G.

Comment: ok, posted question there, let's see
Thanks
G,

Answer (score 0):

I had an answer there:
[Firefox in Ubuntu : how to automate basic authentication password confirm dialog](https://superuser.com/questions/46191/firefox-in-ubuntu-how-to-automate-basic-authentication-password-confirm-dialog)